# How to set MergeOption for a Lazy load using DbContext?

Tags: entity-framework

I am using EF4.2 and DbContext and need to find a way to set MergeOption globally.

So far have looked at the following scenarios:

1. Cast to ObjectContext via the DbContext. With this method I cant seem to see any way of setting the MergeOption, various other posts using ObjectContext enable this but I believe this is a "code gen" ObjectContext.
2. Setting MergeOption for each query: This works for the initial query BUT when I then access a naviagation property a "Lazy load" occurs and this load appears to use the default MergeOption, which is Append.

So is there a way to set the MergeOption for a Lazy load?

Here are some details: Using DbContext POCO EF4.2, lazy loading is true, tracking = true/proxy generation

Any suggestions? Or do I need another approach?

Comment: What do you want to set the `MergeOption` to? To `NoTracking`?